# How do I tell if crew members have more dialogue available?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3, how do I tell if crew members have more dialogue options available after I get back on the Normandy? It would be really nice if I didn't have to go around the ship and talk to everyone to see if there are more conversation options to go through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to say there isn't. You'll just have to talk to everyone, look at a walkthrough, or use your best judgement.

Comment: Yes, though usually there are 2 things that will help, 1. Traynor will comment that someone wants to talk to you and 2. they mostly have new things to say, when you've done a (larger) mission

Comment: At least this time you don't have do go into the full dialog tree to see that someone has nothing to say to you.